# Отменить действие при нажатии колеса мышки на ссылку

Tags: javascript

коллеги!

Есть задача: необходимо при нажатии по колесику мышки на ссылке сделать так, чтобы не открывалась новая вкладка и вообще ничего не происходило. Перепробовал разные варианты.

Пробовал вот такой вариант:

```
function middleClick(e) {
 if (e.which == 2) {
   e.preventDefault();
   open('').close();
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', middleClick);
```

В таком случае, при нажатии на интересующую меня кнопку открывается и сразу закрывается вкладка. К сожалению, такой вариант не подходит, поскольку отлавливает само нажатие по колесику мыши, а не нажатие колеса мыши на ссылке, и в браузере появляется сообщение "Всплывающее окно заблокировано", а это, увы, недопустимо.

UPD: Решение найдено. Естественно, с Вашей помощью. Оставляю скрипт, который отменяет открытие вкладки по клике колесом мыши на ссылку, здесь (на всякий случай, может кому пригодится):

```
    var ourLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
       for (i = 0; i < ourLinks.length; i++) {
          ourLinks[i].addEventListener('auxclick', (e) => {
            if (e.button === 1) {
       e.preventDefault();
  }
});
}
```

Comment: А зачем такое поведение нужно вообще?

Comment: Нужно сделать небольшую демку, планируется засунуть ее на страничку презентации iframe'мом. Нужно, чтобы внутри демки можно было переходить по ссылкам, но только в рамках этого iframe'а.

Comment: Так может просто вырезать у ссылок target=_blank и всё?

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за помощь. Раскрою карты -- я не очень силен в js =) Можете, пожалуйста, описать подробнее как я могу вырезать это дело у ссылок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть событие `auxclick`, которое срабатывает при клике на неосновную кнопку мыши, то есть обычно это скрол и правая кнопка, правда поддержка браузерами у него не на самом высоком уровне - https://caniuse.com/#feat=auxclick

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a');
link.addEventListener('auxclick', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Есть более кроссбраузерный способ: при нажатом колесе запрещать события мыши на ссылках и разрешать обратно, когда кнопка отпущена при помощи св-ва `pointer-events`, которое работает во всех популярных браузерах. Только вешать тогда события нужно на родителя, т.к. если повесить на саму ссылку, то после установки для ссылки `pointer-events: none`, событие `mouseup` на ней уже не сработает и ссылка останется некликабельной.

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 1) {
    link.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 1) {
    link.style.pointerEvents = 'unset';
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: Вадим, благодарю! Ваш способ работает =)